# Caddy URL re-write from blog.mysite.com to mysite.com/blog

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I have a ruby on rails application running, and I use caddy for reverse proxy.

I have my blog generated by jekyll, being served from github.com, to the domian - blog.mysite.com

What edits do I need to do in my Caddyfile serving mysite.com so that, the blog is served on the same domain, for instance :

`blog.mysite.com/01/article/first-article` be served as `mysite.com/blog/01/article/first-article`.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try something using the redir instruction ? https://caddyserver.com/docs/redir

Comment: tried, did not work.

Comment: what's the output of curl when hitting  `blog.mysite.com/01/article/first-article` ?